# DDOS-Deflate won't update iptables

Tags: iptables, centos7, ddos, deflate

I am using DDoS-Deflate (https://github.com/jgmdev/ddos-deflate) in my CentOS 7 server. I installed it successfully. I use iptables as the firewall. The DDoS-Deflate bash script could detect abnormal http requests and log the IP. But the iptables is not updated and so the IP is not blocked.

Suppose the IP is a.b.c.d
The command in the DDoS-Deflate bash looks like:

```
## Original script: $IPT -I INPUT -s "$1" -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -s a.b.c.d -j DROP
```

If I run the above-mentioned command manually using root account, the iptables will update and block the IP. What may be the issue for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check logs, including audit/selinux logs. Have your script create debug logs by adding (temporarily only) at the start something like: `exec 2>>/tmp/debug ; set -x`.